# Один материал отображается по разному в разных сценах

Tags: unity3d

Если создать новый проект 3D, открыть его, будет по умолчанию сцена. 
Создать на ней 3D объект(куб например) От будет белый. Материал по умолчанию.

Но если создать новую сцену, и добавить объект на ней. То тот же материал по умолчанию будет темный, как будто серый.

При этом я создавал новый материал, свой и добавлял к объектам в разных сценах.
Эффект тот же. В одной сцене объект серый в другой белый.

Я сразу подумал про свет. Но все сцены по умолчанию одинаковые. 
Настройки света проверит то знаков поле запятой, все одинаково.

Проверял на двух системах Windows и Linux и на 2х версиях Unity 2019.2.17 и  2019.2.19

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуй включить AutoGenerate для света(во вкладке  Lighting)

Comment: Спасибо. Именно в этом и была проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу сам.

В новой сцене не создан свет.

Необходимо зайти в  Window > Rendering > Lighting Settings

И или нажать на кнопку Generate Lighting.

Или установить флажок "Auto Generate", как это сделано в сцене по умолчанию.

Описание окна:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GlobalIllumination.html